# How do I suppress the "ISO C++ does not support ‘__int128’ warning?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-warnings, int128

I'm compiling my code with gcc, with the `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` switches and a non-extension standard set (say it's `-std=c++14`). But - I want to make an exception to that rule and use `__int128`. This gets me a warning:

```
warning: ISO C++ does not support ‘__int128’ for ‘hge’ [-Wpedantic]
```

Can I suppress the specific warning about `__int128`? Alternatively, can I temporary suppress `-Wpedantic` before and after the use of this type?

Comment: Have you added a `-std=` flag to select a specific C++ standard? Please tell us *all* flags you pass to the compiler.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Edited.

Comment: I did some more experimentation. The original answer had a kludge because the proper use of `__extension__ ` is a bit non-intuitive. The answer is amended with the straightforward solution.

Comment: With `-std=c++14` you tell the compiler to adhere more strictly to the C++ standard, without GCC extensions. Try e.g. `-std=gnu++14` instead to enable GCC extensions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I _want_ adherence to the C++ standard. `gnu++14` will allow code that contradicts the standard, while `__int128` is not standardized, but is  AFAICT  a "legitimate" extension.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If we consult the [documentation for `-Wpedantic`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options) we can note the following:

> Pedantic warnings are also disabled in the expression that follows `__extension__`.

A quick [bit of experimentation](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/329e3c52d69caa43) shows that this allows one to define variables as expected, even under the flag:

```
__extension__ __int128 hge{};
```

But of course that's rather cumbersome if we intended to use this type often. The way to make this less intractable is with a type alias. Though we need to be careful here, **the `__extension__` attribute must precede the *entire* declaration**:

```
__extension__ typedef __int128 int128;
```

You can see it working [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32bdf526b3a79938).

---

An alternative approach, and one that follows your original line of thought, is to use diagnostic pragmas around the type alias:

```
namespace my_gcc_ints {
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wpedantic"
    using int128 = __int128;
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
}
```

Which also [works rather well](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17cb90631002c1cb).